# Is MariaDB restricted to localhost per default?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This question may sound strange, but I haven't found any official documentation, so I'm asking it here.

In MySQL and MariaDB you have the possibility to specify `bind-address` in the options file. If you limit this to `127.0.0.1` or `::1`, the communication is limited to localhost only.

I would be interested to know what is the default of MariaDB and MySQL if `bind-address` is not specified?

Is all communication then restricted to localhost by default or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it is open spurce, anybody can change the default settings, but unchanged it is 127.0.0.1.

If you use `localhost` as connection host the connection is first done by sockets(linux)/ pipe (windows) and if that doesn't work it tries TCP/IP.

> Some MariaDB packages bind MariaDB to 127.0.0.1 (the loopback IP address) by default as a security measure using the bind-address configuration directive. Old MySQL packages sometimes disabled TCP/IP networking altogether using the skip-networking directive. Before going in to how to configure these

[source](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/)